# Powershell/batch uninstall script works locally but not when using invoke-command

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a script that installs an .exe with some arguments remotely to a list of servers that works fine. When I try to do almost the exact same thing but run the uninstall.exe that gets installed to C:\Program Files (x86)\ it won't work.

When I run the scripts on the server locally, it kicks off the uninstall. When I try to run the exact same script or command using the powershell **invoke-command** it won't work.

```
$serverlist = Get-Content -Path C:\NagiosInstall\test.txt

ForEach ($server in $serverlist) {

New-Item -Path "\\$server\C$\" -Name "NagiosInstall" -Force -ItemType "directory"
Copy C:\NagiosInstall\ncpa-2.1.6.exe \\$server\C$\NagiosInstall\ncpa-2.1.6.exe
Copy C:\NagiosInstall\install.bat \\$server\C$\NagiosInstall\install.bat

invoke-command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {C:\NagiosInstall\install.bat}

Start-Sleep -s 15
invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {Remove-Item -LiteralPath "C:\NagiosInstall" -Force -Recurse}

}
```

The install .bat is just a simple command to silently install that ncpa-2.1.6.exe.

Above is my install script, that part all works fine.

```
invoke-command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\uninstall.exe" -ArgumentList "/S"}
```

Running the above command, nothing happens. No errors, nothing.

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\uninstall.exe" -ArgumentList "/S"
```

But running the above command in powershell that's running as admin locally on the server and it works just fine.

I've also tried the same approach to create and copy and run a batch file, very similar to the above "install" code. Same thing... nothing happens but if you run the batch locally on the server, it works just fine. I can post this code if anyone is interested.

I'm guessing it has to do with the **invoke-command** or the fact that it's in C:\Program Files (x86) which might make the syntax different, but I've tried many things and I'm out of ideas besides making an account and posting here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `Invoke-Command` runs non-interactively, and therefore cannot run as Administrator and respond to a UAC prompt.

The only workaround is to connect to the computer via a PSSession with credentials, and execute it that way:

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $Cred
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\uninstall.exe" -ArgumentList "/S"}
$Session | Exit-PSSession
```

---

Edit:

The reason that the installer works is that the UAC prompt for Windows Installs is different than anything else in Windows see: [How to Silence the UAC Prompt for Per-Machine MSI Packages for Non-Admins](http://csi-windows.com/blog/all/27-csi-news-general/335-how-to-silence-the-uac-prompt-for-per-machine-msi-packages-for-non-admins) or [Using Windows Installer with UAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/using-windows-installer-with-uac).

Essentially, Windows Installer (already running as admin and UAC approved), is what runs the install on your behalf, and it is *Windows Installer* and installer settings that determines if you need to see a UAC prompt or not. Hence, this is why the install works. Windows Installer determined that you did not need to see the UAC prompt, and the install proceeds.

Uninstalling is different. Since you are running `uninstall.exe`, the **executable** needs admin access and Windows will do UAC *before* the `uninstall.exe` even runs.

Comment: OK that makes sense why that example I listed isn't working. What still confuses me is why the install works. Am I getting around that issue by copying the .exe and .bat and running them on the server? If that work around worked for the install, why am I unable to get it to work for the uninstall? I tried copying and running an uninstall bat that just silently runs the uninstall.exe but it can't get it work with the invoke-command, just locally on the server.

Comment: Yeah it seems odd that the installer works but uninstall doesn't, so I did a bit of research and it's because of Windows Installer. See edits to the post above.